# Angular Token based authentication - why is "x-access-token" not being sent

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple angular authentication that based on x-access-token

when debugging the code i see that x-access token is not being sent

the code is attached:

```
.factory('authInterceptorService', function ($rootScope, $q, $location, $window,authService) {
        var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {};

        var request = function (config) {
            var token = authService.getToken();
            if(token) {
                config.headers["x-access-token"] = token;
            }

            return config;
        };
```

for make it simple:
token exist, and the config.headers is set, i debug it and i see the token added to the config headers,
but on the network i see the following image:

[image: browser network tab]

I'm not sure why the x-access-token is not added to the headers correctly,

if you have any idea, please reply.

other peace of code that can help, this is the angular config:

```
 .config(function ($locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;';
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    })
```

and this is the api request:

```
userInfo: function () {
                var url = GetAPIUrl('userInfo');
                console.log("userInfo : called");
                return $http({
                    url: url,
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

                });
            }
```

I already tried the suggested answers from the web, and added headers directly into the request, it didn't solve the issue,
please H-E-L-P :)

Comment: What's the authInterceptorService for? Aren't you gonna push it to $httpProvider.interceptors?